# Can I setup user "trust" between two Windows 2008 R2 servers without a domain controller?

Tags: windows

I have two servers linked by a private network but not participating in any domain. Is there a way to tell Windows 2008 R2 to trust a user from the other machine?

Comment: The only way for either server to trust another server's users (I'm assuming local user accounts) is to use authentication, which means passwords and possibly certificates.  Perhaps you should describe what you're trying to do and we may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 3):

have the same users and passwords on both servers!

Comment: +1 for peer to peer fun!  Ha, yeah, if this is supported in Windows 2008 R2 (no idea), this would absolutely work.

Comment: Poor man's trust relationship. It'll work.